# Dynamic parallelism programming supported by GTX 550 Ti graphic card?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, cuda, parallel-processing

I am trying to implement simple dynamic parallelism programming example like..

```
__global__ ChildKernel(void* data){
    //Operate on data
}
__global__ ParentKernel(void *data){
    ChildKernel<<<16, 1>>>(data);
}
// In Host Code
ParentKernel<<<256, 64>>(data);
```

They said it is supported in CUDA 5.0 and above. I have CUDA 5.0 installed and working on my system but is the device that is GTX 550 Ti support dynamic parallelism ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not supported.

Dynamic Parallelism requires compute capability 3.5

Your device has compute capability 2.1

You'll find this requirement listed at the bottom of page 1 of the [user guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Dynamic_Parallelism_Programming_Guide.pdf) I linked to in your last question on this subject.

Comment: [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) is a list of CUDA-Enabled GeForce devices with their compute capability.